# Mostrar datos de un documento XML a otro documento HTML5 a través de JS. Modelo DOM

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, table

¡Hola!
Soy nuevo por aquí y por lo que sé sois muy estrictos respecto a la forma de formular la pregunta, así que intentaré hacerlo lo mejor posible.

El problema que me encuentro es el siguiente, tengo el código JS que os muestro a continuación con el que pretendo recorrer los nodos de un documento XML (que también os muestro a continuación para que entendáis mejor) y que me añada en una tabla el valor de los nodos cuyo nombre sea 'modelo'.

Lo que he hecho es un `for` que recorra los nodos del documento XML y a continuación un `if` que escoja los nodos que cumple la condición. Luego creo la fila a insertar, la correspondiente celda y el contenido que quiero mostrar. Lo adjunto todo, y se lo añado a la tabla.

Código JS:

```
function mostrarContenidoXML(){
    var coches = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('coche');
    var contenido = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
    console.log(contenido)
    for (i = 0; i < coches.length; i++){
        for (y = 0; y < coches[i].childNodes.length; y++){
            if (coches[i].childNodes[y].nodeName == 'modelo'){
                nuevaFila = document.createElement('tr');
                nuevaColumna = document.createElement('td');
                col1 = document.createTextNode(coches[i].childNodes[y].textContent);
                nuevaColumna.appendChild(col1);
                nuevaFila.appendChild(nuevaColumna);
                console.log(nuevaFila)

                contenido.appendChild(nuevaFila);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Código XML:

```
<coches>
    <coche origen="ITALIA" grupo="FIAT">
        <marca>FERRARI</marca>
        <modelo>512 BB</modelo>
        <motor>V12 FERRARI</motor>
        <cilindrada>5</cilindrada>
        <potencia>380</potencia>
        <velocidad_punta>280</velocidad_punta>
        <sitio_web>
            http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrari_Berlinetta_Boxer
        </sitio_web>
    </coche>
    <coche origen="ITALIA" grupo="VOLKSWAGEN">
        <marca>LAMBORGHINI</marca>
        <modelo>MIURA</modelo>
        <motor>V12 LAMBORGHINI</motor>
        <cilindrada>3.9</cilindrada>
        <potencia>385</potencia>
        <velocidad_punta>280</velocidad_punta>
        <sitio_web>https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamborghini_Miura</sitio_web>
        <sitio_web>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamborghini_Miura</sitio_web>
    </coche>
    <coche origen="ALEMANIA" grupo="VOLKSWAGEN">
        <marca>PORSCPE</marca>
        <modelo>964 TURBO</modelo>
        <motor>FLAT 6 PORSCPE</motor>
        <cilindrada>3.6</cilindrada>
        <potencia>360</potencia>
        <velocidad_punta>295</velocidad_punta>
        <sitio_web>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_964</sitio_web>
    </coche>
</coches>
```

Código HTML:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Modelo</td>
                <td>Motor</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Mostrar contenido" onclick="mostrarContenidoXML()">
</body>
```

Comment: Y el problema en concreto es?...

Comment: El error que tengo es que no me reconoce la propiedad `appendChild` para la variable `contenido`, que es la que almacena el cuerpo de la tabla.

Comment: Recuerda que estas seleccionado con `document.getElementsByTagName` esto te genera un `HTMLCollections`, así que el error podría ser que no estás especificando el indice del contenido, tendría que ser `contenido[0].appendChild...`, verifica y comenta que sucede.

Comment: Efectivamente, ahí estaba el error Vick. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: No hay de que un gusto poder ayudarte! :)